# Iterate through JSON to retrieve single variable

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

I have a JSON local file that looks like:

```
{
    "sites" : [
        {
            "name" : "Somename",
            "url" : "https://url.com",
            "api" : "http://url.com/api",
        },
        {
            "name" : "Somename2",
            "url" : "https://url2.com",
            "api" : "http://url2.com/api",
        }

}
```

Each `api` has a single integer data that I need to store in the database. How do I iterate such JSON in Javascript? As soon, as I'm able to retrieve that api url I will be able to write another function and get the integer i want. What I've tried was:

```
function getNetworkData(){
    $.getJSON('../json/sites/site-list.json', function(data) {

    var sites = JSON.parse(data);

    sites.forEach(function(data){
        console.log(data.sites[0].name)
});

});
}
```

...but that just doesn't work. I keep getting an error:

> Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: check your result in `sites` before you parse it. what you get there?

Comment: Your local JSON file has syntax errors. Check at https://jsonlint.com

Comment: No need to `JSON.parse` here, since the $.getJson is already doing that for you. Other than that, that json specifically is wrong (extra commas), as @Tomalak said above. However, since you mention that the json is "looking like" the one you posted, maybe it's not the json itself to problem, but just the extra parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `$.getJSON` already parses the response from the server/source.

So, you don't need to parse it using `JSON.parse`, further, you're trying to loop using the array as follow:

```
sites.forEach
```

What you really want is loop the attribute `sites`:

```
data.sites.forEach(function(s){
    console.log(s.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
function getNetworkData(){
  $.getJSON('../json/sites/site-list.json', function(data) {

    data.sites.forEach(function(site){
        console.log(site.name)
    });

  });
}
```

The object you are looping through doesn't need the index.

`site` is already equal to sites[0] on the first loop, sites[1] on the second loop etc, so you just need site.name

Comment: Now it's ok `(:`

Answer (score 1):

You already got JSON, there is no need to parse. Refer [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Update from

```
var sites = JSON.parse(data);

    sites.forEach(function(data){
        console.log(data.sites[0].name)
});
```

to

```
data.sites.forEach(function(site){
    console.log(site.name); // prints name
    console.log(site.api); // prints api
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip `JSON.parse(data)`; You will get an object with `$.getJSON()` that you can manipulate. See [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)